# T-SQL: Evaluate ISNUMERIC before join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ansi-sql

I am working with a SQL query whereby I need to filter based on an ISNUMERIC return value.  The ISNUMERIC is important because on my join, I implicitly convert the value to an "int", so VARCHARs are a no-no.

I've looked at the order that queries are supposed to be processed in, and the FROM is processed and then the ON which is before the WHERE.  Is there a way I can suggest that the ISNUMERIC be evaluated first WITHOUT using a Subquery?  I'm not against Sub-Queries, I'm just wondering.

```
SELECT l.* FROM [dbo].[CRM_SD_Working_1] l
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[CRM_SD_Working_1] r  ON l.[PlzVon] = r.[PlzBis] + 1
WHERE 
ISNUMERIC(l.[PlzVon]) = 1 
AND ISNUMERIC(l.[PlzBis]) = 1 
AND l.PlzVon <> l.PlzBis
AND r.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Shouldn't that clause be `ISNUMERIC(r.[PlzBiz] = 1`?  With an r. instead of an l.?

Comment: Put a CASE statement in the JOIN on either side of the = sign to test for IsNumberic().

Comment: Do you have any data similar to this `'$5.1', '1.4e1','4d9'` in `PlzVon` or `PlzBis` column ?

Comment: Not even sure you could do it with a sub query.   The query optimizer chooses an order for processing.   A #temp table should work.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just put the `isnumeric` into your `on` criteria?

This works for me:

```
declare @a table(a nvarchar(10))
declare @b table(b nvarchar(10))

insert into @a values('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('a'),('5')
insert into @b values('1'),('2'),('3'),('5'),('6'),('b')

select *
from @a a
    left join @b b
        on(case when isnumeric(a.a) = 1
                then a.a
                else null
                end
           =
           case when isnumeric(b.b) = 1
                then b.b + 1
                else null
                end
            )
```

If you are on version 2012 or higher, you can also use `try_convert`:

```
declare @a table(a nvarchar(10))
declare @b table(b nvarchar(10))

insert into @a values('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('a'),('5')
insert into @b values('1'),('2'),('3'),('5'),('6'),('b')

select *
from @a a
    left join @b b
        on(try_convert(int, a.a) = try_convert(int, b.b)+1
          )
```

Comment: the question is b.b + 1

Comment: make them both nvarchar and put a chat in a and it fails

Comment: @Paparazzi  Cheers for the heads up, answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is guaranteed to work but works for this data
The answer from iamdave looks good to me

```
declare @a table(a varchar(10))
declare @b table(b varchar(10))

insert into @a values('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('c')
insert into @b values('1'),('2'),('3'),('5'),('6'),('a')

select *
from 
( select a from  @a where isnumeric(a) = 1 ) aa
left join 
( select b from  @b where isnumeric(b) = 1 ) bb
on aa.a = bb.b + 1
```